# I tried to fetch data from firestore but in the console show empty array on flutter

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I tried to fetch data from firestore to chips but the console showed an empty array. And when click chips colour change to blue colour.To fetch data I used model that's class name "Words12"
My collection name is "12words" at that collection have two fields "wordName"and "categoryName". I want display only "wordName" as chips

**this..**

```
I/flutter (14273): []
```

my full code

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:hexcolor/hexcolor.dart';
import 'package:kathana/utils/config.dart';

import '../screens/wordsBefore18/database/words12model.dart';

class uitry4 extends StatefulWidget {
  const uitry4({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<uitry4> createState() => _uitry4State();
}

class _uitry4State extends State<uitry4> {
  //list
  List<Words12> wordList = [];
  //collection path
  Future<List<Words12>> fetchRecords() async {
    var records = await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('12words').get();
    return mapRecords(records);
  }

  List<Words12> mapRecords(QuerySnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>> records) {
    var _wordList =
        records.docs.map((data) => Words12.fromJson(data.data())).toList();

    for (var element in _wordList) {
      print("name = ${element.wordName}");
    }
    print("length = ${_wordList.length}");
    return _wordList;
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    print(wordList);
  }

  List<String> selectedWord = [];
  List<String>? deSelectedWord = [];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    double height = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
    double width = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        decoration: const BoxDecoration(
          image: DecorationImage(
              image: AssetImage(Config.app_background4), fit: BoxFit.fill),
        ),
        child: SafeArea(
            child: Center(
                child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 14, right: 0),
              child: Column(
                children: [
                  SizedBox(
                    width: width * 0.94,
                    height: height * 0.30,
                    child: Column(
                      children: <Widget>[
                        const SizedBox(height: 16),
                        FutureBuilder<List<Words12>>(
                            future: fetchRecords(),
                            builder: (context, snapshot) {
                              if (snapshot.hasError) {
                                return Text('Error: ${snapshot.error}');
                              } else {
                                wordList = snapshot.data ?? [];

                                return Wrap(
                                  children: wordList.map(
                                    (word) {
                                      bool isSelected = false;
                                      if (selectedWord!
                                          .contains(word.wordName)) {
                                        isSelected = true;
                                      }
                                      return GestureDetector(
                                        onTap: () {
                                          if (!selectedWord!
                                              .contains(word.wordName)) {
                                            if (selectedWord!.length < 50) {
                                              selectedWord!.add(word.wordName);
                                              deSelectedWord!.removeWhere(
                                                  (element) =>
                                                      element == word.wordName);
                                              setState(() {});
                                              print(selectedWord);
                                            }
                                          } else {
                                            selectedWord!.removeWhere(
                                                (element) =>
                                                    element == word.wordName);
                                            deSelectedWord!.add(word.wordName);
                                            setState(() {
                                              // selectedHobby.remove(hobby);
                                            });
                                            print(selectedWord);
                                            print(deSelectedWord);
                                          }
                                        },
                                        child: Container(
                                          margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                                              horizontal: 5, vertical: 4),
                                          child: Container(
                                            padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                                                vertical: 5, horizontal: 12),
                                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                                color: isSelected
                                                    ? HexColor('#0000FF')
                                                    : HexColor('#D9D9D9'),
                                                borderRadius:
                                                    BorderRadius.circular(18),
                                                border: Border.all(
                                                    color: isSelected
                                                        ? HexColor('#0000FF')
                                                        : HexColor('#D9D9D9'),
                                                    width: 2)),
                                            child: Text(
                                              word.wordName,
                                              style: TextStyle(
                                                  color: isSelected
                                                      ? Colors.black
                                                      : Colors.black,
                                                  fontSize: 14,
                                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w600),
                                            ),
                                          ),
                                        ),
                                      );
                                    },
                                  ).toList(),
                                );
                              }
                            }),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ))),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

model

```
import 'dart:convert';

Words12 words12FromJson(String str) => Words12.fromJson(json.decode(str));

String words12ToJson(Words12 data) => json.encode(data.toJson());

class Words12 {
  Words12({
    required this.id,
    required this.wordName,
    required this.categoryName,
  });
  String id;
  String wordName;
  String categoryName;

  factory Words12.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Words12(
        id: json["id"],
        wordName: json["wordName"],
        categoryName: json["categoryName"],
      );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "id": id,
        "wordName": wordName,
        "categoryName": categoryName,
      };
}
```

How I get data from firestore?

Comment: where do you print?

Comment: I tried to fetch in UI  but not displayed then I added print in the initState to check through the console

Comment: could you print("data = ${records. docs}"); before var wordList inside mapRecords?

Comment: Then on console show this " I/flutter (14273): data = [Instance of '_JsonQueryDocumentSnapshot', Instance of '_JsonQueryDocumentSnapshot', Instance of '_JsonQueryDocumentSnapshot', Instance of '_JsonQueryDocumentSnapshot', Instance of '_JsonQueryDocumentSnapshot', Instance of '_JsonQueryDocumentSnapshot', Instance of '_JsonQueryDocumentSnapshot', Instance of '_JsonQueryDocumentSnapshot']
W/System  (14273): Ignoring header X-Firebase-Locale because its value was null.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try change `mapRecords()` to this :

```
List<Words12> mapRecords(QuerySnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>> records) {
    var _wordList = records.docs
        .map(
          (data) => Words12.fromJson(data.data()) 
        )
        .toList();

    return _wordList;
}
```

and also change your if condition in your `FutureBuilder`:

```
if (snapshot.hasError) {
       return Text('Error: ${snapshot.error}');
} else {
  wordList = snapshot.data ?? []; //<--- change this
  ...
}
```

also change wordList to this:

```
class _uitry4State extends State<uitry4> {
  List<Words12> wordList = []; //<--- change this
  ...
}
```

and this:

```
children: wordList.map(
    (word) {
        bool isSelected = false;
        if (selectedWord!.contains(word.wordName)) {
           isSelected = true;
        }
        return GestureDetector(
             onTap: () {
                if (!selectedWord!.contains(word.wordName)) {
                    if (selectedWord!.length < 50) {
                        selectedWord!.add(word.wordName);        
                        deSelectedWord!.removeWhere(
                            (element) => element == word.wordName);
                        setState(() {});
                        print(selectedWord);
                    }
                } else {
                   selectedWord!.removeWhere(
                       (element) => element == word.wordName);
                   deSelectedWord!.add(word.wordName);
                   setState(() {
                          // selectedHobby.remove(hobby);
                   });
                   print(selectedWord);
                   print(deSelectedWord);
                }
             },
             child: Container(
                 margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 5, vertical: 4),
                 child: Container(
                             padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 5, horizontal: 12),
                             decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                    color: isSelected ? HexColor('#0000FF'): HexColor('#D9D9D9'),
                                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(18),
                                    border: Border.all(
                                            color: isSelected ? HexColor('#0000FF') : HexColor('#D9D9D9'),
                                            width: 2)),
                             child: Text(
                                 word.wordName,
                                 style: TextStyle(color: isSelected
                                                      ? Colors.black
                                                      : Colors.black,
                                                  fontSize: 14,
                                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w600),
                                 ),
                             ),
              ).toList(),
```

also change your model class to this:

```
  factory Words12.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Words12(
    id: json["id"] ?? "",
    wordName: json["wordName"]?? "",
    categoryName: json["categoryName"]?? "",
  );
```

Comment: I added this but now show me Error: type 'Null' is not a subtype of 'String' on the UI and on the console display " I/flutter (14273): [] "

Comment: on the snapshot.data ?? [];  show me a error "A value of type 'List<Object>' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'List<String>'. (Documentation)  Try changing the type of the variable, or casting the right-hand type to 'List<String>'."

Comment: I updated again my answer.

Comment: I added that now on the " return GestureDetector(
                                        onTap: () {
                                          if (!selectedWord!.contains(word)) {
                                            if (selectedWord!.length < 50) {
                                              selectedWord!.add(word);   " , display error on "word" this "The argument type 'Words12' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'String'. (Documentation)"

Comment: your previous logic was base on the string but now you are getting Words12 object not string so you need change all word. check out new update on my answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/248821/discussion-between-dasun-dola-and-eamirho3ein).

Comment: and also on the console display I/flutter (17055): []
W/DynamiteModule(17055): Local module descriptor class for com.google.android.gms.providerinstaller.dynamite not found.
I/DynamiteModule(17055): Considering local module com.google.android.gms.providerinstaller.dynamite:0 and remote module com.google.android.gms.providerinstaller.dynamite:0
W/ProviderInstaller(17055): Failed to load providerinstaller module: No acceptable module com.google.android.gms.providerinstaller.dynamite found. Local version is 0 and remote version is 0.

Comment: And I edited the question added new code

Comment: I updated my answer, check it out. @DasunDola

Comment: One more thing you need is replace wordList.map with wordList.forEach when you are trying to build Wrap's children. @DasunDola

Comment: Yeah . How to do that can you provide an example code

Comment: check out my last update. @DasunDola

Comment: When the added wordList.forEach display this error "This expression has a type of 'void' so its value can't be used. "

Comment: could you update your question to see how do you do that?

Comment: I changed agian foreach to map .... now it's working perfectly . Thank you So Much

Answer (score 1):

Just convert

```
 List<Words12> mapRecords(QuerySnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>> records) {
    var wordList = records.docs
        .map(
          (words12) => Words12(
            id: words12.id,
            wordName: words12['wordName'],
            categoryName: words12['categoryName'],
          ),
        )
        .toList();

    return wordList;
  }
```

to

```
 List<Words12> mapRecords(QuerySnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>> records) {
    var wordList = records.docs
        .map(
          (words12) { 
           print(words12);
          return
           Words12(
            id: words12.id,
            wordName: words12['wordName'],
            categoryName: words12['categoryName']
        );}
        .toList();

    return wordList;
  }
```

and check what you get , also on a sidenote the way your using FutureBuilder is not ideal

```
Future _fetch = Future(() async {
    var records = await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('12words').get();
    return mapRecords(records);
  })
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your support I tried it but when the added this code  "The body might complete normally, causing 'null' to be returned, but the return type, 'List<Words12>', is a potentially non-nullable type. (Documentation)" show this error.

Comment: try the edited code

Comment: I tried when added your code display this error "The method 'toList' isn't defined for the type 'Function'. (Documentation)"